# DeleteByQueryRequest socket timeout exception - java high level rest client api

Tags: elasticsearch, socket-timeout-exception, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-rest-client, elasticsearch-api

I'm a beginner to elasticsearch and I want to delete a huge amount of document which matches to the particular query. I'm using DeleteByQueryRequest for this purpose. I tried the code below.

```
String fileName="output2.log";
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")));
DeleteByQueryRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteByQueryRequest("_all");
deleteRequest.setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("fileName.keyword",fileName));
deleteRequest.setTimeout(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(10));
//deleteRequest.setRefresh(true);
BulkByScrollResponse bulkResponse = client.deleteByQuery(deleteRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
client.close();
System.out.println(bulkResponse.isTimedOut());
System.out.print("Deletion done");
```

When I run this code, the respective documents gets deleted but this code throws the below exception.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]
```

What can be done to get rid of this exception?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i found that the default socket timeout for RestHighLevelClient is 30000ms. I used the below code to extend the socket timeout duration.

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient((RestClient.builder(new 
      HttpHost(localhost,9200,"http"))).setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder ->                         
     requestConfigBuilder                        
    .setConnectTimeout(10000)
    .setSocketTimeout(60000)
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(0)
));
```

Now you can able to increase the timelimit in setSocketTimout() method.